# Apache as a reverse proxy for GitLab Omnibus

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, gitlab

I'm using GitLab Omnibus on a CentOS6.5 server.

The gitlab nginx server listen on the 6543 port (Apache already using 80 and 443).

I want to use Apache as a reverse proxy to access GitLab with that address: gitlab.example.com instead of example.com:6543

So I add an Apache Virtual Host, here is the configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName gitlab.example.com
        ServerSignature Off
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/gitlab_access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/gitlab_error.log
        ErrorLog syslog:local2

        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
            ProxyVia On
            ProxyRequests Off
            ProxyPass / https://example.com:6543/
            ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com:6543/
            ProxyPreserveHost Off
            <Proxy *>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
            </Proxy>
        </IfModule>

        # SSL Config
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com/default.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com/default.key

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!RC4:!3DES:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
        Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2678400"
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName gitlab.example.com
        Redirect / https://gitlab.example.com:443
</VirtualHost>
```

So gitlab and apache are running, but when trying to access gitlab via the proxy server, it fails and output a 500 error.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is GitLab configured to use SSL? You probably don't want it to be, when it's running behind an Apache proxy. Try configuring GitLab to listen to HTTP connections on the 6543 port and set the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse URLs to `http://example.com:6543/` (without the s).